# DisplayCarrierList Hook Alternative on Prestashop 1.7

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I'm trying to create a shipping Module for 1.7, based on 1.6 module.

Everything looks right except the displayCarrierList Hook.

At displayCarrierList I tried to show a list with available relay points, it works perfectly on 1.6, but not in 1.7.

With some searches, I found that displayCarrierList hook is deprecated since 1.7.0 (Ref. https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/blob/develop/classes/Hook.php#L93)

I need to show a list (select) with ajax calls at the order carrier choice step, any idea (without displayCarrierList) ?

Answer (score 0):

You have just to use : DisplayCarrierExtraContent  instead of the deprecated one displayCarrierList.

ref : https://www.waschier-design.at/tutorials/prestashop-1-7-globale-variablen-hooks/

**Display additional content for a carrier (e.g pickup points)
This hook calls only the module related to the carrier, in order to add options when needed**